# Mysql group by missing sequence

Tags: mysql

This is my sql statement.

```
select *
from rpt.project_resource_recommendation_runs pr
where pr.project_id = 'a004M00000VEdN3QAL' and pr.run_id = '202208021659477396'
```

This is my output:

```
    week_of_year    resource_id_reassigned
    2022-w31    103046779
    2022-w32    103046779
    2022-w33    103046779
    2022-w34    103046779
    2022-w41    103046779
    2022-w42    103046779
    2022-w43    103046779
    2022-w44    103046779
    2022-w45    103046779
    2022-w46    103046779
    2022-w47    103046779
    2022-w48    103046779
    2022-w49    103046779
    2022-w50    103046779
    2022-w51    103046779
    2022-w52    103046779
    2023-w01    103046779
    2023-w02    103046779
    2023-w03    103046779
    2023-w04    103046779
    2023-w05    103046779
    2023-w06    103046779
    2023-w07    103046779
    2023-w08    103046779
    2023-w09    103046779
    2023-w10    103046779
    2023-w11    103046779
    2023-w12    103046779
    2023-w13    103046779
    2023-w14    103046779
    2023-w15    103046779
    2023-w16    103046779
    2023-w17    103046779
    2023-w18    103046779
    2023-w19    103046779
    2023-w20    103046779
    2023-w21    103046779
    2023-w22    103046779
    2023-w23    103046779
    2023-w24    103046779
    2023-w25    103046779
    2023-w26    103046779
    2023-w27    103046779
    2023-w28    103046779
    2023-w29    103046779
    2023-w30    103046779
    2023-w31    103046779
    2023-w32    103046779
    2023-w33    103046779
    2023-w34    103046779
    2023-w35    103046779
    2023-w36    103046779
    2023-w37    103046779
    2023-w38    103046779
    2023-w39    103046779
    2023-w40    103046779
    2023-w41    103046779
    2023-w42    103046779
    2023-w43    103046779
    2023-w44    103046779
    2023-w45    103046779
    2023-w46    103046779
    2023-w47    103046779
    2023-w48    103046779
    2023-w49    103046779
    2023-w50    103046779
    2023-w51    103046779
    2023-w52    103046779
    2023-w53    103046779
    2024-w00    103046779
    2024-w01    103046779
    2024-w02    103046779
    2024-w03    103046779
    2024-w04    103046779
    2024-w05    103046779
    2024-w06    103046779
    2024-w07    103046779
    2024-w08    103046779
    2024-w09    103046779
    2024-w10    103046779
    2024-w11    103046779
    2024-w12    103046779
    2024-w13    103046779
    2024-w14    103046779
    2024-w15    103046779
    2024-w16    103046779
    2024-w17    103046779
    2024-w18    103046779
    2024-w19    103046779
    2024-w20    103046779
    2024-w21    103046779
    2024-w22    103046779
    2024-w23    103046779
    2024-w24    103046779
    2024-w25    103046779
    2024-w26    103046779
```

If you notice the sequence of weeks, it basically goes from 2022-w31 to 2022-w34
then 2022-w35 to 2022-w40

```
select min(week_of_year),max(week_of_year) ,resource_id_reassigned
from rpt.project_resource_recommendation_runs pr
where pr.project_id = 'a004M00000VEdN3QAL' and pr.run_id = '202208021659477396' 
group by resource_id_reassigned
```

This is the output

```
    2022-w31    2024-w34    103046779
    2022-w35    2024-w26    106987979
    2022-w32    2024-w20    1000
    2022-w34    2024-w16    1005
```

But I basically want to group by on splitting sequence

So I'm expecting an output like this

```
    2022-w31    2022-w34    103046779
    2022-w35    2024-w26    103046779
    2022-w35    2022-w40    106987979
    2022-w32    2024-w20    1000
    2022-w34    2024-w16    1005
```

I want to group by the breaking sequence.
But its complicated because unless there is a difference in what im grouping with I would not be able to make it happen

Comment: re: "If you notice the sequence of weeks, it basically goes from 2022-w31 to 2022-w34 then 2022-w35 to 2022-w40"  you only show w31-w34 and w41 and onward.  please show sample data giving you your example output.

Comment: it sounds like you have a gaps and islands problem, but its hard to tell without the data your output is coming from

Comment: @ysth yes, all this is for a single project, 106987979 is allocated from 2022-w35 to 2022-w40
and 103046779 is allocated from 2022-w30-2022-w34 
and 2022-w41 to 2024-w26

Comment: again, please show example actual and desired output (you seem to have done this part) and *sample data that generates that output*; your sample data only has 106987979 and has nothing from 2022-w35 to 2022-w40.  you need to do that to make it possible to understand what you are asking

Comment: is there a typo in your expected output and the first 2022-w35 is supposed to be 2022-w41?

Comment: also, what does `select version();` show?

Comment: if indeed your expected output just has a typo, this question does make sense, but how to answer it depends on what `select version();` shows.

Comment: version is 8.0.23

Comment: great.  now please either explain or correct the "2022-w35    2024-w26    103046779" in your expected output